# FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, illegalstateexception, android-runtime

Been trying to get my `IntroActivity.java` to enter my `FmMenu.java` (which is a fragment) and I am getting the following error:

```
02-26 02:10:58.197  25189-25189/com.wlodsgn.bunbunup E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.wlodsgn.bunbunup, PID: 25189
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4007)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4002)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.wlodsgn.bunbunup/com.wlodsgn.bunbunup.FmMenu}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
            at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1761)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1485)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3736)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3697)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4007)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3975)
            at com.wlodsgn.bunbunup.IntroActivity.startMenuActivity(IntroActivity.java:51)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4002)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

**Here is my IntroActivity.java (Where my app start and should enter FmMenu with a button click)**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;

/**
 * Created by WiLo on 2/13/2015.
 */
public class IntroActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        /*getActionBar().hide();*/
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_intro);
        Log.i("BunBunUp", "MainActivity Created");
    }

    /**@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_intro, menu);
    return true;
    }

     @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
     // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
     // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
     int id = item.getItemId();

     //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
     if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
     return true;
     }

     return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
     }**/

    public void startMenuActivity(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(IntroActivity.this, FmMenu.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        Log.i("BunBunUp", "IntroActivity Resumed");
    }

    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        Log.i("BunBunUp", "IntroActivity Paused");
    }

    protected void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        Log.i("BunBunUp", "IntroActivity Stopped");
    }
}
```

**FmMenu.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.app.Activity;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by WiLo on 2/13/2015.
 */
public class FmMenu extends Fragment {

    String[] categoria = {
            "Jeans"
    };

    int[] imagenes = {
            R.drawable.veroxjeans1,
            R.drawable.veroxjeans2,
            R.drawable.veroxjeans3,
            R.drawable.veroxjeans4,
            R.drawable.veroxjeans5,
            R.drawable.veroxjeans6,
            R.drawable.veroxjeans7
    };

    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lay_menufragment, container, false);



        //lista
        ListView lista = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, categoria);
        lista.setAdapter(adapter);

        //galeria de imagenes

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mSectionsPagerAdapter.addfragments(PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(imagenes[0]));
        mSectionsPagerAdapter.addfragments(PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(imagenes[1]));
        mSectionsPagerAdapter.addfragments(PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(imagenes[2]));
        mSectionsPagerAdapter.addfragments(PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(imagenes[3]));
        mSectionsPagerAdapter.addfragments(PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(imagenes[4]));
        mSectionsPagerAdapter.addfragments(PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(imagenes[5]));
        mSectionsPagerAdapter.addfragments(PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(imagenes[6]));

        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        return rootView;

    }

    /**@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lay_menufragment);


    }**/

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        List<Fragment> fragmentos;
        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            fragmentos = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        }

        public void addfragments(Fragment xfragment){
            fragmentos.add(xfragment);
        }


        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return fragmentos.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return fragmentos.size();
        }
    }


    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        private static final String ARG_IMAGE = "imagen";
        private int imagen;

        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int imagen) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_IMAGE, imagen);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            fragment.setRetainInstance(true);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            if(getArguments() != null) {
                imagen = getArguments().getInt(ARG_IMAGE);
            }
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, container, false);

            ImageView imagenView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            imagenView.setImageResource(imagen);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

**MenuActivity.java (which contains navigation drawer and search box)**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

/**
 * Created by WiLo on 2/13/2015.
 */
public class MenuActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnQueryTextListener, OnActionExpandListener{

    /*private TextView texto;*/

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

        /*texto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.texto);*/

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // agregar un nuevo item al menu deslizante
        // Menu
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Contacto
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Catologo
        //navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1), true, "Estrenos"));
        // old Contacto (Pedidos)
        //navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));

        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem menuItem) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Abriendo Busqueda", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem menuItem) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cerrando Busqueda", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
        /*texto.setText("Buscando...\n\n" + s);*/
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
        /*texto.setText(" \n\n" + s);*/
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu3_buscar);

        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

        MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchItem, this);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Pass the event to ActionBarDrawerToggle, if it returns
        // true, then it has handled the app icon touch event
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle your other action bar items...

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new FmMenu();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new FmContacto();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("BunBunUp", "MenuActivity - Error cuando se creo el fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggle
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

**Any suggestion would be appreciated**

Comment: `FmMenu` is not an `Activity`.

Answer (score 1):

You opening Fragment instead of activity..

**Your Code :**

```
public void startMenuActivity(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(IntroActivity.this, FmMenu.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Please change `FmMenu.java` to activity instead of fragment

Comment: Thanks for the reply.... I changed the extension in `FmMenu.java` from fragment to activity and its showing me `Cannot resolve method `getActivity()`` , `Cannot resolve method `getChildFragmentManager()`` **(both under public View onCreateView)**, and error in `super(fm);` **(under public class SectionsPagerAdapter)** which says `FragmentPagerAdapter (android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager) in FragmentPagerAdapter cannot be applied to (android.app.FragmentManager)`

Comment: this all methods are related to fragment you must have to remove.. first you have to read about Activity & Fragment.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, could you please be more specific? I have looked in several websites to try and understand and find a solution hence the reason I am asking here. Any links you might want to recommend? Thanks for the help.